# What does "add-resource" in Android resource xml file do?

Tags: android, android-resources

I found that there are following statement in package/apps/UnifiedEmail package in android source code:

```
<add-resource name="RecipientEditTextViewStyle" type="style" />
```

What does this "add-resource" element mean?

The source code: https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_UnifiedEmail/blob/cm-11.0/res/values/attrs.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<resources>
    <string name="app1_name">MyAppName</string>
</resources>
```

is the same thing as

```
<resources>
    <add-resource type="string" name="app1_name">MyAppName</add-resource>
</resources>
```

so

```
<add-resource name="RecipientEditTextViewStyle" type="style" />
```

is the same thing as

```
<style name = "RecipientEditTextViewStyle"/>
```

Comment: I see, thanks, I have another question then, since we have defined `<style name="RecipientEditTextViewStyle" parent="@style/RecipientEditTextView">...</style>`, why we still need this `add-resource` thing? https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_UnifiedEmail/blob/cm-11.0/res/values/styles.xml